# query.filter cannot return full object

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have the little piece of code below to create the object curve. When a new curve is created then it first runs through the method `__new__`. It checks whether this curve already exists in the database, and if it does, it returns this curve.

When a new curve is created on an empty database, it returns `None`, as expected. If it is created while the `name` already exists, then it throws an error and states `KeyError: 'name'` (not really a lot of info here..).

```
class Curve(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'curve'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    name = Column(String, unique = True)
    type = Column(String)

    # We override the new method to first check if the object already exists
    # If it does exist then we return this object
    def __new__(*cls, **kw):
        x = base.session.query(Curve).filter(Curve.name==kw["name"]).first()
        if x: return x
        return object.__new__(*cls, **kw)

    def __init__(self, type, name):
        self.type = type
        self.name = name
        self.add(False)

    def add(self, commit):
        create(base.session, self, commit, name=self.name)
```

Interestingly, if instead of returning a whole curve, we only return an attribute, e.g.

```
x = base.session.query(Curve.name).filter(Curve.name==kw["name"]).first()
```

then it works just fine...

Any ideas?

Comment: Full stack trace, please.

Comment: Please include a minimum, *complete* and verifiable example. How do you use the class? Do you pass arguments to constructor as positional or keyword arguments? All in all a `@classmethod` would serve as a better factory for this kind of job I think.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try updating your **__new__** method to this.

```
def __new__(cls, **kw):
    x = base.session.query(Curve).filter(Curve.name==kw["name"]).first()
    if x: return x
    return super(Curve, cls).__new__(**kw)
```

Comment: thanks for your comment. I am running the code in Visual Studio where the error is thrown in python.exe. It still says `KeyError: 'name'` at the line `x=base.session.query(Curve).filter(Curve.name==kw["name"]).first()`

Comment: you have to make sure that "name" is present in kw, for that you have to provide **name** explicitly while creating the object. **Curve(name='something')**